# Override a Design Template in a Magento 2 Module

Tags: magento2, layout, template, frontend

When two layout files that reference the same ***Layout name*** come into a merge - it would seem to me that the `design` folder always takes preference.

#### Folder Structure

- `code`

  - `[vendorNameSpace]`

    - `[vendorModule]`
    - `view`

      - `frontend`

        - `layout`

          - `catalog_category_view.xml`
- `design`

  - `frontend`

    - `[thirdPartyThemeVendor]`

      - `[themeName]`

        - `Magento_Catalog`

          - `layout`

            - `catalog_category_view.xml`

#### Layout file

- `code/[vendorNameSpace]/[vendorModule]/view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml`

Whereas this references `template="category/desc_main_column.phtml"` within the `code`:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="vendorNameSpace\vendorModule\Block\Category\View"
           name="category_desc_main_column" 
           template="category/desc_main_column.phtml"
           before="category.products"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Which, additionally - this is also references in the design folder - with the same `.xml`.

- `design/frontend/[thirdPartyThemeVendor]/themeName/Magento_Catalog/view/frontend/catalog_category_view.xml`

This also references `category_desc_main_column` - but inherits from Magento core:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
    <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Category\View"
           name="category_desc_main_column" 
           template="category/desc_main_column.phtml"
           before="category.products"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Now on compile - these two get merged. The `design`  folder's `catalog_category_view.xml` gets *authority* as it seems to get added the merged `.xml` last.

Regardless of how many other modules in `code` reference `name="category_desc_main_column"`.

So in my thinking; Code has `module.xml` to allow sequencing of code dependencies. Although this wouldn't work as `design` isn't a **module** per say.

### `module.xml`

Namespacing in themes work differently; as Module require modules to sequence against, not themes.

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="vendorNameSpace_vendorModule" setup_version="1.0.0">
        <sequence>
            <!-- Reference the design namespace? -->
            <module name="thirdPartyThemeVendor_Catalog" />
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

So in Magento 2, does `design` referenced templates gets absolute authority on the say of a template in `.xml`, regardless how many times it's been referenced in third party modules?

Answer (score 0):

So in Magento 2, does design referenced templates gets absolute authority on the say of a template in .xml?

- **Yes when we talk about layout and there is custom theme available and in active state then first priority is always theme why because ,
  because we are modifying the core layout.**
- **I have faced same issue previously , where i found magento actually checks like layout coming from core files ? if no then its
  straight forward checks to custom theme where we have overrided
  layout and serve the request. if its still not there then its going
  to check to your custom module**  .